# Does a picking operation make sense in clip coordinates?

Tags: opengl, graphics

I have a point in 2D screen coordinates that I want to project to a point on a plane given in clip space. However, does this even make sense as the w coordinate is dependent on the z-Coordinate so linear equations are worthless? Should I use eye coordinates instead?

Comment: If you only have X,Y then the only case where projection into a plane in clip space does make sense is when that plane is parallel to XY-axis plane, because the projected point doesn't depend on Z. For other cases you need the Z of the point being projected.

Comment: Shouldn't intersecting with the plane give me the z?

Comment: For the case I exposed the Z of the projected point is the same Z as all points in that parallel plane.

Comment: Are you sure you want to project in clip space? The resulting w-component will most likely not have any significance. Maybe, you want to explain a few more details of what you want to do. Projection onto a plane works in every space.

Comment: I have points given in screen space and a plane given in clip space. The origin of the plane is a fully mvp matrix transformed 4d coordinate with correctly set w coordinate. The clip-space normal of the plane was calculated from a direction (dx, dy, dz, 0) in world space which was multiplied with the view-projection matrix from the left. My current plan revolves around converting the pixel values to clip space values with coords (x,y,-1,1), calculate the intersection z with the plane, then recalculate x,y and w but there seem to be lots of sign issues etc.

Comment: Then why not project in world space? There are much less culprits there. E.g. you cannot transform a normal with the MVP matrix. You need MVP^-T.

Comment: Wait - say I have a plane normal in world space, then multiplying it with VP^-T would yield the correct clip space normal?

Comment: Yes. That can be derived from the plane equation: `dot(x, n) = 0`. This can be expressed as `n^T * x = 0`. If you transform `x` with a matrix `M`, you want to find the matrix `A` that you need to transform `n`: `n^T A^T M x = 0`. And this is obviously satisfied if `A^T M = I`, hence `A=M^-T`.

Comment: This quite possibly solved all of my problems. Thanks everyone! For some reason, I cannot mark for answered.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was the normal transformation problem. Thanks everyone!